# Stringify bash command from array of arguments for use in "bash -c"

Tags: bash, escape-characters

I would  like to stringify a given command, given as an array.

This would be useful to for example put a command inside a `bash -c`.

For example :

```
cmd=(
  "printf '%s\n'"
  "foo bar"
  "baz bang"
)

stringified="$(transform "${cmd[@]}")"
```

So that : `"${cmd[@]}"` and `bash -c "$stringified"` would give the exact same output for any cmd array.

In my example, that would be :

```
$ "${cmd[@]}"
foo bar
baz bang
```

The value of `stringified="printf \"%s\n\" \"foo bar\" \"baz bang\""` works for my case, but I wish to have a transform function that would properly escape those arguments for me.

Preferably, I would prefer a bash solution, or if that is not the case, with tools that are usually already installed on a linux distribution (printf, echo).

Answer (score 1):

I found a good solution for this (I think it would work for any input array), it uses the `printf "%q"` feature.

You can just write :

```
cmd=(
  "printf '%s\n'"
  "foo bar"
  "baz bang"
)

stringified="$(printf "%q " "${cmd[@]}")"
```

This gives :

```
printf\ \'%s\\n\' foo\ bar baz\ bang
```

## Explanation

The printf "%q" command escapes characters to be used in shell :

> %q     ARGUMENT is printed in a format that can be reused as shell input, escaping non-printable characters with the proposed POSIX $'' syntax.
>
> Source : man printf

By using `"%q "`, all elements in the array are printed and correctly escaped, and since there is a space after the `%q`, all elements will be delimited by a space.